# Integral being less than or equal to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this question:

> 1. If $f(x) \leq  0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ then $\int_a^b f(x) dx \leq 0$.
> 2. If $\int_a^b f(x) dx \leq 0$ then $f(x) \leq  0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.
>
> Are the above statements True of False? Justify your response.

I believe it is asking if the area under the graph between $a$ and $b$ is negative then $f(x)$ will also be below zero on the graph and vice versa. However I'm still not sure how to justify my response.

Comment: What are your answers to $1$ and $2$? We need to address that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is true cause all the upper sums are negative.

the second is false. take the example:

$$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R $$
$x \mapsto -7$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f (0)=+1$.
then $$\int_0^1 f=-7$$ but $f (0)>0$.
Or

$$\int_{\frac {\pi}{2}}^\pi \sin (x)dx=-1$$

but $\sin (\frac {\pi}{2})=1>0$.

Comment: The first part makes sense but I'm not really sure I understand your reasoning for the second part.

Comment: Just take a function, which is linear and growing, but intersetcts the x-axis somehwere after the midpoint if a and b. The Integral is negative, because more than half of the area is under the x-axis, however the function is surley not negative everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**To justify 1.:** If you have $g, g': [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g\leq g'$ (pointwise), then how do the integrals relate (you should have had a theorem like this, it's a basic property of integrals)?

**For 2.,** a counterexample would provide a proof.
A nonzero function $f: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that its integral splits up into two integrals of inverse orientation of same absolute value (i.e., same area between the negative part of the graph and the $x$-axis as between the nonnegative part and the $x$-axis) will do.
There are very simple ones (note that for a counterexample, you are free to choose $a$ and $b$).

Salahamam_'s counterexample will do, but it doesn't have much educational value...